# Calculating length of AD

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following question:

[image]

for question I have worked out question a) and b) i) to be 17.4,

however i'm not sure how to do question b)ii) as I know that AD is not half of AC is there a formula I should use to find this ?

Comment: Using similar math to part a), find $\angle BAC$. Then you can use trig.

Comment: If you know the area, then you know the altitude, which is the length of $BD$. Then use Pythagoras.

Comment: How are the area, AC and BD related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part a) use $$9^2=5^2+7^2-2\cdot5\cdot 7\cos(\beta)$$
For part b)$$S=\frac{5\cdot 7}{2}\sin(\beta)$$
For part c)$$\sin(\alpha)=\frac{BD}{5}$$($$\alpha$$ must be calculated.)

Comment: I got BD to be 3.17 cm is this correct ?

Comment: I got $$BD\approx 3.87$$

Comment: sorry i meant AD = 3.17 cm is this correct ?

Comment: Yes this is correct, $$AD\approx 3.17cm$$

Answer (score 2):

1. step: By cosine rule calculate $\angle ABC$
2. step: By Heron formula calulate the area of triangle
3. step: Calulate $BD$ with formula $$Area = {BD\cdot AC \over 2}$$
4. step: Use a Pyhtagora theorem in triangle $ABD$.

Comment: I got BD to be 3.17 cm is this correct ?

Comment: I didn't go into the details.

Answer (score 1):

You have answered b)i) so you know the area of rectangle $A$, right? You can evaluate $BD$ from the following expression:

$$A =\frac{1}{2}AC\cdot BD$$

After that, you can calculate $AD$ from Pithagora's:

$$ AD^2+BD^2=AB^2$$